# <image>.h - Where is this -e coming from?

Tags: c++, makefile, wxwidgets, header-files

I'm getting the following issue when I try to build this project:

```
drazisil@Lightning:~/comical$ make -C src
make: Entering directory '/home/drazisil/comical/src'
Converting firstpage.png
...

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/travis/build/drazisil/comical/src'

`wx-config --cxx` `wx-config --cxxflags` -O2 -Wall -pipe -D_UNIX -I../unrar -I../unzip -c -o ComicalApp.o ComicalApp.cpp

In file included from ComicalFrame.h:43:0,

                 from ComicalManager.h:32,

                 from ComicalApp.h:32,

                 from ComicalApp.cpp:28:

firstpage.h:2:1: error: stray ‘#’ in program
```

The reason appears to be because there is an -e being inserted in both the beginning and end of of the generated .h files:

```
#ifndef _firstpage_png_h
-e #define _firstpage_png_h
static const unsigned char firstpage_png[] = {
...
...
...
-e };

#endif
```

Since I'm not sure what step of the process is causing this, I'm not sure how to remove it, or what it even means. Searching -e doesn't work all that well.

ETA: Makefile: https://github.com/drazisil/comical/blob/dev/Makefile

How can I fix it?

Comment: What makefile rule is converting the png files to header files?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's part of the issue. The makefile came with the project. I think it's the `make -C src` step, unknown. I linked the full makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is [this target](https://github.com/drazisil/comical/blob/dev/src/Makefile#L15) in the `src/Makefile` file.

```
%.h : %.png
    @echo "Converting" $<
    @echo "#ifndef _"$*"_png_h" > $@
    @echo -e "#define _"$*"_png_h\n" >> $@
    @echo "static const unsigned char "$*"_png[] = {" >> $@
    @hexdump -e "13/1 \"0x%02X, \" \"\n\"" $< | sed 's/0x  ,//g' >> $@
    @echo -e "};\n\n#endif" >> $@
```

Specifically, the two lines that use `echo -e` in an attempt to put an extra newline at the end of the echoed output.

`echo -e`, however, is non-standard and your shell/version of `echo` clearly doesn't understand it.

That target would be better with those lines rewritten as:

```
@printf '#define _$*_png_h\n\n' >> $@
@printf '};\n\n#endif\n' >> $@
```

Additional improvements to that target are also possible but out-of-scope for this problem (mainly to use a single shell command and single redirection instead of five).

Comment: Thank you so much! 1:, I was looking at the wrong makefile, 2: I'm not sure what's wrong with my debian/ubuntu echo that it not only won't take -e (listed in the man) but it's ignoring --version as well so I don't even know what it is.

Comment: What's ignoring `--version`? `echo`? `echo` doesn't take arguments in many shells (which includes dash I believe which is `/bin/sh` on Debian-derived systems at this point as far as I know). The authors of that makefile need to write more portable recipes. You should file a bug with them. The `make -C src` bit came from the toplevel makefile. `-C` says "change to this directory and run `make` again".

Comment: I'm finding this out. It's just very confusing when I run `man echo` and it lists -e and --version as valid, and then won't take them. Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: `man echo` is giving you the information about `/bin/echo` not the shell's builtin `echo`. Try `/bin/echo -e 'foo\nbar'` and it should work.